# Get data from Mobile Service Table

Tags: c#, azure, windows-mobile

I want get data from Azure. This is my code:

```
private async void FindPromotion()
    {
        MobileServiceCollection<Promotions, Promotions> result;
        MobileServiceInvalidOperationException exception = null;

        string _place = textInputPlace.Text;

        if (_place!= null)
        {
            try
            {
                //lista obiektów Category
                result = await todoTable2.Where(todoItem => todoItem.Place==_place)
                    .Select(todoItem => todoItem.Products, todoItem => todoItem.Description)
                    .ToCollectionAsync();                

            }
            catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                exception = ex;
            }

            if (exception != null)
            {
                await new MessageDialog(exception.Message, "Can't find items").ShowAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                ListItems.ItemsSource = result.Distinct();
            }

        }
    }
```

I have error:

No overload for method 'Select' takes 2 arguments.

Anybody know? Is another way to get this data?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can select multiple columns:

```
result = await todoTable2.Select(todoItem => new { todoItem.Products , todoItem.Description}).ToCollectionAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks :) How I can get type string and DateTimeoffSet in object result? When I want do this I have error: Cannot implicitly convert type  MobileServiceCollection<anonymus type: string Products, System.DataTimeOffSett STDate> to 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceCollection<string, string>

Comment: You'r welcome, can you ask another question or update this with the change you made that doesnt work? thanks